# JavaScript trigger custom method on execution of any object method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an object with some added methods to its prototype:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.name = '';
    this.innerData = [];
    this._callbacks = {};
};
MyClass.prototype.add = function(data) {
    this.innerData.push(data);
};
MyClass.prototype.remove= function(data) {
    //This part is working
    for (var i=0; i < this.innerData.length; i++) {
        if (this.innerData[i].desc === desc) {
            this.innerData.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};
MyClass.prototype.on = function(evname, callback) {
    if (!this._callbacks[evname]) {
        this._callbacks[evname] = $.Callbacks();
    }
    this._callbacks[evname].add(callback);
};
```

What I want to do, is a way for triggering ANY methods loaded in the `_callbacks` object, without the need to do an ugly `if (methodIsBound(method)) { ....` within all methods of my class.

E.g.:

```
var c = MyClass();
c.on('add', function() { console.log("Adding data"); });
c.add(someData);
c.add(someData2);
```

So far I tried doing this adding a check in any method, asking if that method is registered in the callbacks, but that is cumbersome, as for any new method I'd need to add the if (which does not belong to that method functionality), and if any other developer wants to add functionality, they will have to know that additional code.

I checked custom events both in pure JS and jQuery, but I definitely not understanding how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you, but are you wanting, every time an event is triggered to fire off its associated callback/callbacks? Why not have another method which you pass the event name to and get that method to check to see if there are callbacks?

Comment: Hi! What I want to achieve is fire every registered method, the ones loaded in the callback object, in an "automatic" way, that is, without asking for it within all the methods. It's like an observable, eg: if you register the 'add' method to be triggered, then any time you call it, the event will be fired. From now on, the only way I found is, within the "add" method, ask if it was loaded in the callbacks object and if so, trigger the registered callback. Not nice definitely.

Comment: it is tough to make a general solution becuase what if you want to do it after or before or in the middle of the trigger...or what if you want custom event objects / arguments for the events being called. it would be best to have some code like this `this.beforeAddEvent.callAll(arg1, arg2)` in all of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the like (**TESTED ON FIREFOX**)?
The idea is to take any method in MyClass.prototype and wrap it inside a function that calls a callback and then the original method. So every time you call the method, the saved callback is called, is that what you need?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>

<script>

var MyClass = function() {
    this.name = '';
    this.innerData = [];
};
MyClass.prototype.add = function(data) {
    this.innerData.push(data);
};
MyClass.prototype.remove= function(data) {
    //This part is working
    for (var i=0; i < this.innerData.length; i++) {
        if (this.innerData[i].desc === desc) {
            this.innerData.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};
MyClass.prototype.on= function(fname,callback) {

    var originalFunction=MyClass.prototype[fname];
    var givenCallback=callback;

    MyClass.prototype[fname]=function() {

       givenCallback.call();
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

       originalFunction.apply(this,args);
    }
};

var c = new MyClass();
c.on('add', function() { console.log("Adding data"); });
c.add("aaa");
c.add("bbb");

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Whith "fixed" parameters and "this" passed to the callback:

```
MyClass.prototype.on= function() {
    var onArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    var originalFunction=MyClass.prototype[onArgs[0]];
    var givenCallback=onArgs[1];

    var callbackArgs=onArgs.slice(2);

    MyClass.prototype[onArgs[0]]=function() {

       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

       givenCallback.apply(this,callbackArgs);
       originalFunction.apply(this,args);
    }
};

var c = new MyClass();
c.on('add', function(a,b) { console.log("Adding data '"+a+"',"+b+" obj:"+this); },"called add",1);
c.add("aaa");
c.add("bbb");
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mgcr0jxj/2/

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your answer. You are calling, within the "on()" method, the method passed as a parameter (let's say, "add") right? But if later on I call again the "add" method, would it be the callback triggered?

Comment: this may cause a stack overflow exception if the `on` function is called a lot on for a single event or an exception if the previous function did not exist

Comment: @LoganMurphy yes, the idea is to call it once, if you need a lot of callbacks the code gets more complicated (you can call many callbacks in one wrapping function) and yes, it is is just a concept, error handling was omitted

Comment: @FrancescoMM thanks very much, your solution helped me a lot!! Now I have to check how to pass variables to the callback, as the arguments that I tried to pass are always null :( Have to study more JS I guess...

Comment: @jmares you can add more parameters to MyClass.prototype.on for fixed parameters to be sent to the callback, or you could pass the same `args` you pass to apply() also to the `givenCallback.call();` so the callback gets all the same arguments of `add` and also `this` as the object.

Comment: @jmares see update for some example of parameter passing

Comment: Thanks very much @FrancescoMM, I tried that yesterday, but I only get 'undefined' in the variables. Obviously they are not in scope. If I do "var a=1; var b=2 " and execute your code, both are undefined. I'm testing and debugging to see what's going on. Guess I fell in the JS scope world. Thanks again!

Comment: @jmares Trying the fiddle to me it writes `Adding data 'called add',1 obj:[object Object]` to the console on Firefox